# Can I disable the screenshot option on the Windows 8 share bar?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8.1, winjs

I am building a Windows 8 store App, and I use the share charm functionality to let the user share files. It has been mentioned, that the "Share a screenshot" functionality that comes with the Share bar is confusing.

Does anyone know if I can disable this option using WinJS somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop, unfortunately it's not possible to do that